# Where can I start the wysiwyg html editor in tinymce to edit an existing html file?

Tags: html, tinymce, editor, wysiwyg

I just want to edit some html files that I already have, using the tinymce wysiwyg html editor please.

I have created a free tinymce account, but have absolutely no idea where to find this editor on the tinybce web pages.  Can anyone please help an absolute newbie, rookie please ?

So far I have only used the ancient  frontpage express to do html editing.

I have created a github account to load in the html files to create a basic website.  I am not sure if tinymce has a link to github.

Or should I use a different editor, not on tinymce ?
Thanks very much,
Simon

Looking for the html editor on all the tinymce website, can't see it anywhere.